HTML Forms with Github
I am trying to put out a test website for me club on github. I am using forms and I am trying to do a dummy login form into a html file, but everytime I press the submit button it won't direct me to the html file. What can I do? If possible I prefer to do this without javascript
<form action="/studentinterface.html" method="post">
        <h1>Student Login</h1>
        <fieldset>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email" placeholder="email@domain.com" value="" required>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="user_password" placeholder="your password" value="" required>
</fieldset>
        <button class="cpoint" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

Login imageAfter Log in clicked
I wanted it to open up my interface.html file, but it would not retrieve it. It works for me if I'm inputting the actual html in the address bar.

The issue you're facing is likely due to how your website is hosted on GitHub. GitHub Pages behaves differently from a traditional web server when handling form submissions. Here's how to fix it without JavaScript:
1. Leverage Form Method (Preferred):
Change the method attribute of your form to GET. This will append the form data to the URL after a question mark (?).
HTML
<form action="/studentinterface.html?message=success" method="get"></form>

Explanation:
By using GET, the browser will include the form data in the URL as key-value pairs (e.g., user_email=example@domain.com&user_password=yourpassword). This allows your studentinterface.html to potentially access this data (though limited for security reasons).
2. Manual Redirection (Alternative):
If using GET isn't ideal, you can achieve redirection within your current HTML file. However, this approach doesn't send data to the next page.
HTML
<form action="" method="post">
  <button class="cpoint" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script> // A small script snippet
  function redirectOnSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
    window.location.href = "/studentinterface.html"; // Redirect to desired page
  }
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", redirectOnSubmit);
</script>

Explanation:
This method uses a small JavaScript snippet to intercept the form submission. It prevents the default behavior and then redirects the user to studentinterface.html using window.location.href.
